# Obtaining whenCreated property for user with Microsoft Graph

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to capture the whenCreated property of user from the REST API of Graph. It seems this data is not in the response, however I can get it when calling Get-UserMail in powershell. Is this property exposed anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK , currently create time of user could not be directly retrieved by using Microsoft Graph api , you could get creation data for users via the reporting/auditing APIs in beta(Using Azure AD Graph API):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-reporting-audit-events/

Please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-audit-reference#activity) for more about Azure Active Directory audit API .